# Return results ordered by total matches on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+---------+------------+
| EntryID | CategoryID |
+---------+------------+
|      11 |         15 |
|      11 |         18 |
|     186 |         15 |
|     186 |         18 |
|     186 |        334 |
|     187 |         15 |
|     187 |         18 |
|     187 |        337 |
|     278 |         15 |
|     278 |         18 |
|     278 |        337 |
|     278 |        457 |
+---------+------------+
```

I'd like to get results in the order of how relevant the matches are, which is a percentage of `CategoryID rows / CategoryIDs specified`.

Where I am stuck on is that this calculation needs to work on multiple `categoryID`s queries. For example, if I were to look up `categoryID` 18, `entryID` 11 should come first because it has a Match Percentage (excuse me for the cliche naming) of 50%, then either 186 or 187 comes second with a Match Percentage of 33% (in my use case, sorting ondoesn't matter), then 278 would come last with a Match Percentage of 25%.

My question is: **Is there a way to do this kind of sorting in one/multiple SQL query/queries?** Java is available on hand so I can sort with Java instead of MySQL, but I'd like to see if there is a pure-SQL solution. Additionally, **is there a better way to calculate the relevance in my case?**

(And just for fun, **is there a better title to this question?**)

Comment: there is certainlya  way, i'm just not sure what you want as an answer... could you draw the resulting table after the query you asked has run?

Comment: @Daren What I'm looking for as a result? The list of `entryID`s sorted by relevance. See paragraph 2 for an example.

Comment: A better title to the question could be: how to calculate the relative frequency of a value in sql? (I think that ordering is the main topic)

Comment: Sorry, errata corrige: I think that ordering is NOT the main topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sound likes you want something like this:

```
select EntryID, count(*)
from your_table
group by EntryID
order by count(*) asc
```

UPDATE: Based on the updated question, here's a way to accomplish that:

```
select your_table.EntryID, count(*) as matches, sub_query.total_rows
from your_table
inner join (
  select EntryID, count(*) as total_rows
  from your_table
  group by EntryID
) sub_query on sub_query.EntryID = your_table.EntryID
where your_table.CategoryID = 18
group by your_table.EntryID
order by (count(*) / sub_query.total_rows) desc
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify - I need this to work on multiple `categoryIDs` as opposed to just one.

Comment: Shoudnt be matches/sub_query.total_rows?

Comment: @Mihai Matches over `categoryID`s specified.

Comment: `order by (count(*) / sub_query.total_rows) asc` scares me- what if `total_rows` is zero? Now we're dividing by it and the universe implodes.

Comment: In this query `total_rows` will never be zero. The sub query will only have rows for `EntryID` values that appear in the table at least once.

Comment: @Ike to be perfect the order by should be desc. For the rest good query.